# Getting "Incompatible magic value 0" while on cmd javac -version

Tags: java, eclipse

I am getting error while open my eclipse and when i cmad javac -version i am getting error

> "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassFormatError: Incompatible magic value 0 in class file javax/tools/StandardJavaFileManager"

Could you please help me to fix this

Os : windows 10
java versions
java version "11.0.6" 2020-01-14 LTS
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 18.9 (build 11.0.6+8-LTS)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 18.9 (build 11.0.6+8-LTS, mixed mode)

Stack Trace

```
  at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass2(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1108)
        at java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:206)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.defineClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:759)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.findClassInModuleOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:680)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClassOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:605)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClassOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:640)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClassOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:609)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:579)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass2(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1108)
        at java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:206)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.defineClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:759)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.findClassInModuleOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:680)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClassOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:605)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:579)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.main.Main.compile(Main.java:169)
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.Main.compile(Main.java:57)
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.Main.main(Main.java:43)
```

Comment: it is jdk11.06 downloded from oracle

Comment: Your Java insallation seems to be broken. So try to uninstall your Java 11.0.6 and install the newer 11.0.8 instead (e.g. from [adoptopenjdk.net](https://adoptopenjdk.net/) which will provide longer long term support for free than those from Oracle).

Comment: @ howlger    It Works!!!  Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

Your **Java insallation seems to be broken**.

So, try to **uninstall** your Java 11.0.6 **and install the newer Java 11.0.8** instead (e.g. from [adoptopenjdk.net](https://adoptopenjdk.net/) which will provide longer long term support for free than the one from Oracle you have; or Java 11.0.8 from Oracle or from somewhere else which should work too).